# Why does my GFCI trip randomly?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have a GFCI in the kitchen has started tripping all of a sudden.  It may trip several times a day. I have the same things plugged in that I have had for months. Nothing has changed with the usage so not sure what the problem might be.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely as simple as a bad/weak GFI receptacle, especially if it is older.

Have you tried leaving it with nothing plugged in?
Are there other receptacles on the LOAD side of this GFI?

Comment: There is one test/reset hooked to 3 outlets on another wall that are not test/resettable.  On the GFIC outlet there are two things plugged in and 1 thing on the load side.  The house is 4 years old.  I have not tried leaving it with nothing plugged in.

Comment: @CatherineShaw, I would unplug everything from that GFI and load side receptacles. Leave it this way for as long as you can (days). See how it goes. If it still trips it is almost certainly the GFI itself.